# can I have one model which uses two methods in the some controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently developing a asp.net mvc application. I was wondering if I can have one model (my database) and then have one controller which contains two methods which access the same model but retrieve different rows?

I have a database and I would like to use the same controller to access the same database but need two methods in that controller as I am trying to get different rows of data and present it in two different views?

Comment: if you can type same part of your code, i can try to help

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to understand the question but you might want to improve it a bit.

So in general practise a controller can be used to process different requests either based on:

1. A controller per page.
2. Controller for a section of page (view) categorised by functionality.
3. Controller based on data/model its retrieving.

There are other ways by which controllers are defined.

In your case, the controller interacts with the same Model(DB) and returns data for two different views.

Assuming that the model(DB) is for a certain purpose/ stores certain data, this is an acceptable way of using the controller.

You need to also consider other portions of the application and how you've coded it. Having a convention across the codebase and arriving at that convention of how you want to separate the controllers will give you a better idea and will be more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Just to confirm it is ok If I have two methods in my controller which access the same model.

Comment: Yes, both the methods are for different purposes and renders data for different views.